# run the shell script from rails application after login to the remote system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, remote-access, remote-execution

I want to run a shell script from my Rails application. The script is started on the remote server via the `net-ssh` Gem. Here is my code:

```
Net::SSH.start('localhost', 'user', :password => '1234', :port => port) do |session|
  session.exec!("#{Rails.root}/script/myscript")
end
```

I have checked that the script is present in my local application. Script is taking about 1 hour for completion. I have two questions:

1. Is this the right way for doing this?
2. How can I run the script in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [sample doc](http://ruby.about.com/od/networking/qt/netssh.htm) says that the simple, and quite proper way to run the `Net::SSH` session is the following:

   ```
   HOST = '192.168.1.113'
   USER = 'username'
   PASS = 'password'

   Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do| ssh |
      result = ssh.exec! 'ls'
      puts result
   end
   ```

   I recomment to pass at least password argument via shell environment to don't store it in the script plainly. Also you could use [`micro-optparse` gem](https://github.com/florianpilz/micro-optparse) to pass other argument via command line. So it could be as follows:

   ```
   require 'micro-optparse'

   options = Parser.new do |p|
      p.banner = "This is a fancy script, for usage see below"
      p.version = "fancy script 0.0 alpha"
      p.option :host, "set host", :default => 'localhost'
      p.option :host, "set user", :default => ''
   end.parse!

   Net::SSH.start( options[ :host ], options[ :user ], :password => ENV[ 'PASSWORD' ] ) do| ssh |
      result = ssh.exec! 'ls'
      puts result
   end
   ```

   And run from command line:

   ```
   $ bundle exec ./1.rb --host=111.ru --user=user
   {:host=>"111.ru", :user=>"user"}
   ```

   Of course the support for `:port` argument can be added in the same manner.
2. Use [`nohup`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) or [`screen`](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) utitilies to run a script as a service in linux:

   ```
   result = ssh.exec! "nohup #{Rails.root}/script/myscript"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why shouldn't it be the right way?
2. To run a shell script in the background, append `&` to the command

For example:

```
session.exec!("#{Rails.root}/script/myscript&")
```

Comment: can it will effect on rails server that running?

Comment: Your shell script is a separate process so no, not as long as your shell script doesn't bring the entire machine to a halt.

Comment: Hi tried but not worked I also tried with `session.exec!("sh #{Rails.root}/script/myscript&")` did I miss something

Comment: when i check the pid for it it dosen't return anything.

Comment: How do you retrieve the pid?

Comment: I have print the output of the execution in logger. but it not displayed.

Comment: process is taking about 1 hr